# Don;t understand error

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to make a program and I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "E:\MyAi.py", line 27, in <module>
        ask = raw_input(statements[randint(0,len(answers) - 1)])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is my code:

```
if ask[len(ask) - 1] == "?":
    questions.append(ask)
    ask = raw_input(answers[randint(0,len(answers) - 1)])
elif ask[len(ask) - 1] == "!":
    answers.append(ask)
    ask = raw_input(statements[randint(0,len(answers) - 1)])
else:
    statements.append(ask)
    ask = raw_input(questions[randint(0,len(answers) - 1)])
```

Why is my code causing this? i can't figure out why.

Comment: This is not your full code. Show how you define your variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably meant to do this:

```
ask = raw_input(statements[randint(0,len(statements) - 1)])
```

and also this:

```
ask = raw_input(questions[randint(0,len(questions) - 1)])
```

Otherwise if `answers` is bigger than your other lists, you run the risk of getting the error you got.

Comment: Oh yeah! thanks! i just forgot to put the right list for the length function.